# Cant resolve a SimPy simulation attribute check error

Tags: python, attributeerror, simpy

Stuck with an error I cant get passed. Here is what I am trying to solve and the code.
Problem:
In this problem you, can simulate a simplified airport security system at a busy airport. Passengers arrive
according to a Poisson distribution with λ1 = 5 per minute (i.e., mean interarrival rate µ1 = 0.2 minutes)
to the ID/boarding-pass check queue, where there are several servers who each have exponential
service time with mean rate µ2 = 0.75 minutes. [Hint: model them as one block that has more than one
resource.] After that, the passengers are assigned to the shortest of the several personal-check queues,
where they go through the personal scanner (time is uniformly distributed between 0.5 minutes and 1
minute).

`

```
import random
import simpy


## define system constraints
# checkers = number of boarding pass checkers
# scanners = number of scanners
num_checkers = 10
num_scanners = 25
r_seed = 500

# define rates
arrival_rate = 5 # rate is passengers per minute
check_rate = .75 # rate is minutes per passenger
min_scan = .5 # scanner min time - uniform distribution
max_scan = 1.0 # scanner max time - uniform distribution

# define simulation timing
run_time = 100 # minutes per simulation
reps = 100 # number of simulation replications


# initalize global variables - will store answers in these variables later
checkWait = 0
scanWait = 0
sysTime = 0
timeWait = 0
timeChecker = 0
timeCheckerComplete = 0
timeScan = 0
timeScanComplete = 0
passenger_count = 0





## SimPy simulation framework


# create the simulation object - airport includes checkers and scanners
class Airport(object):


    # define the overall resources in our system - checkers and scanners
    def __init__(self, env):

        # set up the enviroment
        self.env = env

        # set up checkers as resource = # checkers
        self.checker = simpy.Resource(env, num_checkers)


        # set up scanners as a resource - each scanner has it's own queue!
        self.scanners = []

        # for each scanner - assign a resource - multiple scanners with 1 resource
        for i in range(0,25):
            resource = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
            self.scanners.append(resource)



    # define how long a passenger gets to the checkout
    def check(self, passenger):
        yield self.env.timeout(random.expovariate(1/check_rate))


    # define how long a passenger takes to scan themselves in
    def scan(self, passenger):
        yield self.env.timeout(random.uniform(max_scan , min_scan))






# define attributes of a passenger - how passenger moves through the system (checkers, scanners)
def passenger(env, name, s): # enviroment, name, system reference

    # initalize global variables - will store answers in these variables later
    global checkWait
    global scanWait
    global sysTime
    global timeWait
    global timeChecker
    global timeCheckerComplete
    global timeScan
    global timeScanComplete
    global passenger_count



    # time passenger arrives
    timeArrive = env.now
    print('%s arrives at time %.2f' % (name, timeArrive))



    with s.checker.request() as request:
        yield request
        print('check queue length = %d' % len(s.checker.queue))

        # time passenger arrives at checker
        timeChecker = env.now
        print('%s gets to checker at time %.2f' % (name, timeChecker))

        yield env.process(s.check(name))

        # time passenger completes checker
        timeCheckerComplete = env.now
        print('%s complete checker at time %.2f' % (name, timeCheckerComplete))



    min_q = 0

    with s.scanners[min_q].request() as request:
        yield request
        print('scanner queue length = %d' % len(s.scanners[min_q].queue))

        for i in range(1, num_scanners):
            if (len(s.scanners[i].queue) < len(s.scanners[min_q].queue)):
                min_q = i

        # time passenger arrives at scanner
        timeScan = env.now
        print('%s gets to scanner at time %.2f' % (name, timeScan))

        yield env.process(s.scan(name))

        timeScanComplete = env.now
        print('%s complete scanner at time %.2f' % (name, timeScanComplete))




    # time at the end of entire system process
    timeExit = env.now
    print('%s gets to complete system time %.2f' % (name, timeExit))






    sysTime = sysTime + (timeExit - timeArrive)
    checkWait = checkWait + (timeChecker - timeArrive)
    scanWait = scanWait + (timeScanComplete - timeCheckerComplete)
    timeWait = (checkWait + scanWait)






def setup(env):

    airport = Airport(env)

    i = 0

    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1.0 / check_rate))
        i += 1
        env.process(passenger(env, 'Passenger %d' % i, airport))


# define variables to store simulation results into
avg_wait_time = []
avg_check_time = []
avg_scan_time = []
avg_sys_time = []


for i in range(0, reps):

    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(setup(env))
    env.run(until = run_time)

    avg_wait_time.append(timeWait / 125)
    avg_check_time.append(checkWait / 125)
    avg_scan_time.append(scanWait / 125)
    avg_sys_time.append(sysTime / 125)

    passenger_count = 0
    sysTime = 0
    checkWait = 0
    scanWait = 0
    timeWait = 0


sim_wait_avg = sum(avg_wait_time) / reps
sim_check_avg = sum(avg_check_time) / reps
sim_scan_avg = sum(avg_scan_time) / reps
sim_sys_time = sum(avg_sys_time) / reps


print('Average cummulative wait time: ' + str(sim_wait_avg))
print('Average cummulative check time: ' + str(sim_check_avg))
print('Average cummulative scan time: ' + str(sim_scan_avg))
print('Average cummulative system time: ' + str(sim_sys_time))
```

`

Error I am getting:

`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/4r/z339ff2521g9hm6t9_krqctw0000gn/T/ipykernel_16484/1087764229.py in passenger(env, name, s)
     27 
---> 28         yield env.process(s.check(name))
     29 

AttributeError: 'Airport' object has no attribute 'check'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/4r/z339ff2521g9hm6t9_krqctw0000gn/T/ipykernel_16484/2180799163.py in <module>
     22     env = simpy.Environment()
     23     env.process(setup(env))
---> 24     env.run(until = run_time)
     25 
     26     avg_wait_time.append(timeWait / 125)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simpy/core.py in run(self, until)
    252         try:
    253             while True:
--> 254                 self.step()
    255         except StopSimulation as exc:
    256             return exc.args[0]  # == until.value

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simpy/core.py in step(self)
    204             exc = type(event._value)(*event._value.args)
    205             exc.__cause__ = event._value
--> 206             raise exc
    207 
    208     def run(

AttributeError: 'Airport' object has no attribute 'check'
```

`

I've tried variations of the airport variable but still coming back to the attribute error.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code, and it runs to completion for me.  My guess is you are using an IDE and you forgot to save before you ran this, so you're getting an older version of Airport that didn't have `check`.

Comment: Must have been it. Thank you.